# decryption works using PHP (openssl) and not working using javascript (cryptojs)

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, php-openssl

Decryption works using php/openssl and I can get my plain data. Here is the defined call:

```
<?php

function decryptString($data, $key)
{
    return base64_decode(openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($data), "AES-256-CBC", $key, true, "h7oehNIHWGNIHxyN"));
}

function encryptString($data, $key)
{
    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt(base64_encode($data), "AES-256-CBC", $key, true, "h7oehNIHWGNIHxyN"));
}

echo 'encrypted: ' . encryptString('my sample text', '7f7720b911c2ecbb22637ed7adef41e82d44b6a0') . "\n";

echo 'decrypted: ' . decryptString('rFWejB1Pj6W3Gh1bheFqDZPMO9POKbhGPOP6eAH9BSk=',        '7f7720b911c2ecbb22637ed7adef41e82d44b6a0') . "\n";
```

and I get this output:

```
encrypted: rFWejB1Pj6W3Gh1bheFqDZPMO9POKbhGPOP6eAH9BSk=
decrypted: my sample text
```

I tried to implement this same function using [cryptojs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js), but things are not working, and I get "Malformed UTF-8 data" sometimes and sometimes others ambiguous errors (Empty string / Canno't read property length of undefined depending on the code change I do). So here is the best I did so far: ( I have "Malformed UTF-8 data" error at the moment)

```
function decryptData(encrypted, pass) {
    // encrypted is a base64 encoded string
    let data = let data = Buffer.from(encrypted, "base64").toString();  // I tried this also [ let data = crypto.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted); ]

    let key = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(pass);
    let decrypted = crypto.AES.decrypt(data, key,
        {
            iv: crypto.enc.Hex.parse('h7oehNIHWGNIHxyN'), // tried passing it as a simple string like this [ iv: 'h7oehNIHWGNIHxyN', ]
            mode: crypto.mode.CBC,
            padding: crypto.pad.NoPadding // I tried also with [ crypto.pad.Pkcs7 ]
        }
    );
let result =  decrypted.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8); //  tried this also [ let result = decrypted.toString(crypto.enc.Base64) ]
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
/home/vagrant/PhpstormProjects/untitled3/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:513
                    throw new Error('Malformed UTF-8 data');
                    ^

Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
    at Object.stringify (/home/vagrant/PhpstormProjects/untitled3/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:513:24)
    at WordArray.init.toString (/home/vagrant/PhpstormProjects/untitled3/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js:268:38)
    at decodeBase64String (/home/vagrant/PhpstormProjects/untitled3/decryptor.js:13:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/PhpstormProjects/untitled3/decryptor.js:19:1)
```

This might seem pretty obvious but I feel confused, and nothing seems to work. Could you please help me out?

Questions I Tried to follow with no luck:

- [CryptoJS AES Unable to decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989586/cryptojs-aes-unable-to-decrypt)
- [Encrypt with PHP, Decrypt with Javascript (cryptojs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337317/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-javascript-cryptojs)
- [AES decryption in crypto-js returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62203444/aes-decryption-in-crypto-js-returns-empty-string)

**Update 1**:
I edited the question to add a sample plain message and full php encryption/decription example along with my last code's version.

Comment: I tried to follow you I'm sorry I couldn't. Could you please post your implementation using code so I see it working and I can understand it (code would be more understandable than words. Thank you in advance @Topaco :)

Comment: Sure, I' ve posted a possible CryptoJS implementation for the decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES is only defined for 16/24/32 bytes keys. You are using a 40 bytes key. PHP implicitly cuts the key to 32 bytes, CryptoJS does not, but processes the key without error message due to a bug ([#293](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293)), with a wrong result, of course.
Also, the ciphertext must be passed as `CipherParams` object or Base64 encoded, the IV must be Utf8 encoded, PKCS7 padding should be used, and the decrypted data is a base64 string (and still needs to be Base64 decoded).

The following CryptoJS code decrypts the sample ciphertext:

```js
function decryptData(encrypted, pass) {

    let decryptedWA = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        encrypted,                                              // Pass ciphertext Base64 encoded (or as CipherParams object)
        CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pass.substring(0, 32)),         // Truncate key to 32 bytes
        {
            iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('h7oehNIHWGNIHxyN'),    // UTF8 encode the IV 
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,    // default
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 // default              // Apply PKCS7 padding
        }
    );

    let decryptedB64 =  decryptedWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); 
    let decrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(decryptedB64).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); // Base64 decode the decrypted data

    return decrypted;
}

var ciphertext = "rFWejB1Pj6W3Gh1bheFqDZPMO9POKbhGPOP6eAH9BSk=";
var key = "7f7720b911c2ecbb22637ed7adef41e82d44b6a0";
console.log(decryptData(ciphertext, key));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that a static IV is insecure (but maybe you are only using a static IV for testing purposes).

Comment: works like a charm, thank you!
I see the tricky points now (cutting the key down to 32 bytes / the iv Utf8 paring and the Pkcs7 padding required). Regarding the static iv, I have no control over the encryption process (external provider) but thanks for the note!