# Encrypt with flutter/dart and decrypt aes with CryptoJS returns empty string

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I have encrypted in flutter using dart library [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt). Below is the code sample:

```
  import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as enc;
  final key = enc.Key.fromUtf8('Thisisasamplekeythatamusinginmyc'); //32 chars
  final iv = enc.IV.fromUtf8('thisismysampleiv');//16 chars

  String encryptMyData(String text) {
  final e = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key));
  final encrypted_data = e.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
  return encrypted_data.base64;
  }
```

I am able to encrypt but the issue arises when I try to decrypt the code using this code in JavaScript, using Crypto-JS:

```
const cryptkey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('Thisisasamplekeythatamusinginmyc');
const crypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("fdsUYHdv/5PoJSoZGwWppw==");

var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: crypted}, cryptkey, {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('thisismysampleiv'),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

console.log(decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

The problem is that it always returns an empty string, even using the AES.js library.

I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989586/cryptojs-aes-unable-to-decrypt) but same issue exists.

Comment: The plaintext to your sample data is missing.

Comment: That can be anything, any text you use. the function is  encryptMyData("Sample Text")

Comment: The posted Dart code does not return the ciphertext `Ck4F8zbx79xebKbsdPKtsg==` for the plaintext `Sample Text` when using the key `Thisisasamplekeythatamusinginmyc` and the IV `thisismysampleiv`. Check this again.

Comment: No this is just text sample data. Whatever it returns, how do i decrypt it in javascript that is my question. Thank you @Topaco

Comment: You make it unnecessarily difficult to answer the question. How is the reader supposed to know that the test data is inconsistent? Please post _valid and complete_ test data!

Comment: I have edited the question with valid cypherText `fdsUYHdv/5PoJSoZGwWppw==`. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CryptoJS code is incomaptible because the IV is decoded incorrectly. Instead of the Hex encoder, the Utf8 encoder must be used.
Also, the *encrypt* library applies the CTR mode by default. Therefore, in the CryptoJS code the CTR mode must be used instead of the CBC mode:

```js
const cryptkey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('Thisisasamplekeythatamusinginmyc');
const cryptiv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('thisismysampleiv')

// Decryption 
const crypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("fdsUYHdv/5PoJSoZGwWppw==");
var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: crypted}, cryptkey, {
    iv: cryptiv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR
});
console.log(decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

// Encryption
var encrypt = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Sample Text", cryptkey, {
    iv: cryptiv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR
});
console.log(encrypt.toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

---

Usually no padding is used for a stream cipher mode like CTR. Note that both libraries apply PKCS#7 padding by default and do not automatically disable it for a stream cipher mode. Therefore, the padding should be *explicitly* disabled on both sides (with `padding: null` on the Dart side and `padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding` on the CryptoJS side).
Alternatively, a block cipher mode like CBC can be used on both sides. Then, padding *must* be applied (e.g. PKCS#7).

If a static IV is used beyond testing and a password for the key: Then, for security reasons, a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 should be applied. Also, for each encryption, a random IV should be generated, which is passed to the other side along with the ciphertext (typically concatenated).

Comment: Wish i could upvote twice. Thanx @Tapaco. Any chance you could add how to encrypt sample using the same keys. Thank You once again

Comment: @vinshaba - Sure. I have added the encryption.